# Proving that (2^n mod 7) is repeated

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

How do I prove that $2^n \mod 7$ is repeated?

I know that sequence $A_n = 2^n \mod 7$ repeats $2, 4, 1$ for $n \ge 1$.

But I don't know how to prove this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the finite field with $7$ elements as a ring of integers modulo $7$ and investigate the order of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Find the order $m$ of $2$, that is, the smallest positive natural number $m$ such that $2^m\equiv_7 1$.

Then look at $$2^{mk}, 2^{mk+1},\ldots, 2^{mk+(m-1)}\mid k\in\Bbb N$$

In short, if $A_n$ repeats, then it should have a period $m$, such that $A_n=A_{n+mk}$.

---

*Since no answer has been accepted, I'll add the details:*

We have $A_3=2^3\equiv_7 1$, therefore $A_{3k}=2^{3k}=(2^3)^k\equiv_7 1^k\equiv_7 1$, and so $$A_{3k}=1, A_{3k+1}=2,A_{3k+2}=4$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that $A_{3k}=1$, $A_{3k+1}=2$, $A_{3k+2}=4$.